# Is there a way to start/open the console from a WinForms/WPF application?

Tags: .net, console

I have a windows forms application and i want to open a console on demand (when i press a button for example) that i can interact with using the standard Console class. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there is you'll need a litte bit on interop with Win32 to do it.

```
public class ConsoleHelper
{
    public static int Create()
    {
        if (AllocConsole())
            return 0;
        else
            return Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    }

    public static int Destroy()
    {
        if (FreeConsole())
            return 0;
        else
            return Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Security", "CA2118:ReviewSuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityUsage"), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool AllocConsole();


    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Security", "CA2118:ReviewSuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityUsage"), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool FreeConsole();
}
```

Now you can call Create() to create console window associated with your app.

Comment: thanks. it worked. now i have another problem. if the spawned console is closed my whole application goes down. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: Not easily.  You could try disabling the close functionality using the techniques in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/877839/stop-a-net-console-app-from-being-closed/878334#878334

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Eric Petroelje's [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807998/how-do-i-create-a-c-app-that-decides-itself-whether-to-show-as-a-console-or-wind/808045#808045).  It shows code that can create a console at runtime.