# How to prevent a windows console application from closing?

Tags: windows, console-application

I have a console application which can take longer than 5 seconds to close down gracefully. However, if a user clicks the close button on the title bar, windows seems to forcefully terminate the application. By using [SetConsoleCtrlHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I managed to delay the termination by 5 seconds. Is there a way to extend this delay?

Comment: Have a look at this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/877839/stop-a-net-console-app-from-being-closed

Comment: One option, failing all else, would be to separate your application into two processes - a console process for interacting with the user, and a process with no console to do the actual work.  The latter could then take as long to close as it needed to, although if the user logs out or the system shuts down it will eventually be forcibly terminated.